SSR based control of window blind motor with protection
I have a pair of separate SSRs based on the G3MB 202P. Both are controlled by 5V logic from the MCU. Pin 2 of connectors J1 and J3 are fixed to 5V. The Input0 and Input1 are directly attached to the MCU port. The SSRs have internal serial resistors which are not depicted here. J2 and J4 control a motor (230 V at 50 Hz) to open or close a window blind. Applying voltage to J2 opens the blind, while J4 closes it. If voltage is applied to both J2 and J4 simultaneously, the motor will be damaged.
Because of potential motor damage I'd like to make a minimalistic protection in case of firmware failure. Unfortunately, I have no access to neither VCC nor GND and therefore I improvised in a way depicted below to make a logic XOR based on transistor logic, but it does not seem to work. I did test it and it is always turned on but not fully. It is like a 50 Hz PWM with 50% duty cycle... The SSR alone works properly Any idea how to approach it properly?
SSR LED forward current is typically 10 mA (20 mA max) while the MCU can drive 20 mA (I am using PORTF and PORTL from ATmega2560).


Have you confirmed that the MCU can drive the SSRs directly, without the transistors? Maybe it simply can't sink enough current.

Might help if you told us which pins and which MCU you're using.

"Pin 2 of connectors J1 and J2 are fixed to 5V", I think this is an error, and you mean to say "J1 and J3"?

You also haven't included how the 230V is applied to the motor which may be relevant.

LED forward current is typically 10 mA (20 mA max) while the MCU can drive 20 mA (I am using PORTF and PORTL from ATmega2560).

@LordTeddy Yes! It is a typo! I am going to correct it. Thank you!

@noonespecial you should also edit your main question to include responses to comments, and also expand on "does not seem to work". What exact behaviour do you get? How have you tested it?

@LordTeddy, "you should also edit your main question to include responses to comments" what do you mean?

Yes, I did test it and it is always on but not fully. It is like a 50 Hz PWM with 50% duty cycle... The SSR alone works properly

NOTE: I am using 230V AC power supply @ 50 Hz

@noonespecial when your question gets a lot of questions like "what MCU are you using?" you should edit your question to include these points. That way, if someone new looks at your question, they don't have to dig through the comments to get all the information, it's now in the question.

Thank you @LordTeddy. I updated it accordingly.

I did another test with regular LED and it worked very well. This is strange. Maybe not enough current is going to the SSR. Or maybe to high voltage drop on diode and the transistor... I do not know. Just guessing
